# Deletar uma linha especificar de um DataTable

Tags: c#, webforms, datatable

Como posso deletar uma linha especificar de um `DataTable`  e depois recarregar um `ViewState` com o restante das linhas que ficaram? tenho o seguinte caso abaixo, mas não estou conseguindo deleta diretamente do `DataTable`.

```
protected void rdItens_DeleteCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        string ID = e.Item.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues[e.Item.ItemIndex]["Id"].ToString();
        DataTable table = (DataTable)ViewState["ItensGrid"];

        var linha = table.Rows.Find(ID);
        linha.Delete();

        ViewState["ItensGrid"] = table;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
table.Rows[indice].Delete(); 
table.AcceptChanges();
```

Comment: o [indice] nesse caso é o meu ID?

Comment: isso, coloquei como indice só pra ficar um pouco mais claro.

Comment: Perfeito, só não entendi o que o `AcceptChanges() ` faz.

Comment: O AcceptChanges() aceita as modificações.